# python wkhtmltopdf - exited with exception - wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code -11

Tags: python, aws-lambda, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am using pdfkit in python lambda for generating Html to pdf files. I am able to generate pdf without charts but failing for chartjs code.

HTML

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("segment-chart");
var label = ["Mid", "Top", "Bottom"];
var series = [20, 40, 10];
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "doughnut",
    data: {
        labels: label,
        datasets: [{
            data: series,
            backgroundColor: ["#f38b4a", "#56d798", "#ff8397", "#6970d5"],
            borderColor: ["#6970d5", "#6970d5", "#6970d5", "#6970d5"],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            position: "right",
            align: "middle",
            labels: {
                usePointStyle: true,
                boxWidth: 6,
            },
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 0,
        },
        hover: {
            animationDuration: 0,
        },
        responsiveAnimationDuration: 0
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:250px;height:250px;">
    <canvas id="segment-chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Attached python code snippet for reference

```
...

try:
    pdfkit.from_file("/tmp/input.html", "/tmp/output.pdf", options=options)
except Exception as e:
    print("failed while converting to pdf. exception = " + str(e))
    exit(0)
...
```

I am getting below error

```
failed while converting to pdf. exception = wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code -11. error:
Loading pages (1/6)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
[==========>                                                 ] 18%
[==================>                                         ] 30%
[===================>                                        ] 32%
[========================>                                   ] 41%
[==========================>                                 ] 44%
[===========================>                                ] 46%
END RequestId: 1xxxxxx xxx xxx
REPORT RequestId: xxxxxx xxx xxx    Duration: 1971.80 ms    
Billed Duration: 1972 ms    Memory Size: 512 MB Max   
Memory Used: 146 MB Init Duration: 435.24 ms
```

Configurations :

```
Timeout - 30 Seconds
Memory - 512 MB
Ephemeral storage - 512 MB
```

Comment: Can you try to increase your memory limits?  According to [some older bugs](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2592) this is due to memory constraints.

Comment: Tried but no luck. As per the log, it is not consuming more than 150 MB.